# When will setFetchSize() and setMaxResults() actually filter the result set with Oracle 11g?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

If I have a table called ACCOUNTS that has one million records and I issue the following Criteria query, when does the filtering of the number of records returned take place? I'm interested in whether or not the results of the query would differ when .setFetchSize(100) is and is not included in the query. With setFetchSize(100), will Oracle fetch only 100 records then order them?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Accounts.class)
    .setFetchSize(100)
    .setMaxResults(100)
    .addOrder(Order.desc("acct_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that number should be interpreted as the limit that gets built into the sql query itself (e.g. WHERE ROWNUM <=100). You can make sure of that by enabling Hibernate SQL logging and inspecting the given query.